# Can anyone work on the closing questions queue?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

After we have fixed the [edit queue](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/718/8212) problem (thanks to JasonC and Kate), I suggest we tackle the next one.

I'm flagging multiple of questions as off-topic almost every day, and none to almost none get closed.

Is this because again, there are not enough high reputation users to close questions, is it because of me flagging too much, or is there just not the awareness that the queue for off-topic questions is currently stacked with 29 items?

Comment: This one is going to much more difficult, since it requires 5 users to close, unlike edits which require "only" 2 to approve. I doubt this site has 5 active users with more than 500 reputation. (I don't even mention moderators because they are not relevant as they don't do anything on the site.)

Comment: Actually edits can be approved by one person if you choose "improve" and make at least one little change.

Comment: @KateGregory I see. So just removing a trailing white space is sufficient then? That doesn't really solve the issue with closing questions though, sadly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard surely, the site would benefit from more users with higher rep, but since there is a reference constraint for answers (which is absolutely necessary) gaining reputation doesn't go as quickly as on other sites. Moreover, most of the active members aren't here for rep points anyway. That being said, stating that the mods don't do anything isn't just incorrect it's also quite unfair. All my flags that require moderators' attention get resolved promptly. Narusan, as for the "trick" with the edits I would use it sparingly - there is a reason why 2 users should approve an edit.

Comment: @Lucky The problem is that so many first posts need editing. I can't edit for multiple days now because of the 6 edits that are in the queue, five are mine. As I have now passed the closing-reputation threshold, I'll help there.

Comment: @Lucky moderators should also close questions and delete crap. None of those is done here for long time. That is a fact nobody can deny. Hence, I say with utter certainty that the moderation on this site is a total failure and that is a FACT. Handling custom flags is NOT enough, moderators have other tasks. Personally I don't care, and in this stage I believe this site is beyond salvaging (so I'm not spending time on it, it is waste of time), just stating my frustration and the reason.

Comment: @Lucky To rephrase Shadow Wizards point more softly: In my opinion, moderators should be in touch with the site. I have not seen a recent answer or a comment by any of them. This is the issue I see with moderation. Another big problem is that there is not enough voting going on. Most answers attract +2 upvotes at most, which is, given the long research time, even less reputation is gained and less users will pass the 500 reputation threshold. This is a big problem in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I only get on the site every 3-4 months, but I'm working through the queue now, and it's always been atrocious.  I'm sure I'll be hitting my review limit.

There is a rep problem, and I suggest we go through users with several answers under their belts and try to up-vote the worthy ones a lot as a community.  You might think "eh this seems like a +4 answer," but in reality, we should be up-voting all the correct ones we can to help overcome this problem.

From the get go, this site has attracted way, way more bad content, and has been much harder to moderate because of the combination of general interest and the need for rigorous response.  In my mind, the best idea for that will be to actively find quality users and try to up-vote their content (probably with a focus on sub 2k reputations).

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve with [The excellent answers of Health.SE](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/726/8212). This will  ensure that well-researched answers get a lot of upvotes. Sadly, so far there has been no participation by anyone. No comment, no other proposals...

Comment: @Narusan  I'm getting there....lots of reviews to go through first (at edit limit, about to be at the VTC limit), then up-votes, then I'll post something there.  I would say, however, rather than looking at posts from people over 2k (who have mod tools), I'd focus on the under 2k user group, which isn't quite the same.

Comment: Only one user is above 600 rep from the answers that I nominated. Thanks for taking care of this site!

Comment: Regarding this: *In my mind, the best idea for that will be to actively find quality users and try to up-vote their content (probably with a focus on sub 2k reputations).* I've just pushed L.B. from 450 to 505 (being able to cast close and open votes now). She deserves it and is always actively reviewing and commenting and improving answers.

Comment: @Narusan unfortunately, of your excellent answers, I only felt comfortable voting up 2, and one was michaelpri, who is over the 2k mark.  This is not to say that your model is poor, rather that we need more options to go through.  In my sporadic remaining time in the day, I will try to find a few more.

Comment: I will not poste more than three nominations until some time in the future, because this is supposed to be a Community project, not me telling everybody what answers are excellent. This is why I encourage you to look for answers that you find excellent. It obviously is up to personal opinion...