# The excellent answers of Health.SE

Tags: discussion, answers

*Inspired by the same Meta Threads on other Stackexchange sites*

Health.SE has many great answers. Below is a collection of answers that are well-researched and well-written.

- Each post should only contain a link to one answer and an explanatory paragraph why this answer is excellent.
- Thus, please do not post your own answer.

I have went on and posted a link [Excellent answer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/726/8212) under all my nominated answers. It's up to you to follow this practice or not.

Comment: Should this be a wiki?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, but I have now idea how to make it one.

Comment: Just ticking the wiki box when editing it posting it?

Comment: @Ooker The box does not appear when I edited the question. I can make answers Community Wikis, but there seems no point in doing that because, obviously, they are personal nominations and not done by the Community

Answer (score 3):

### [Answer by michaelpri about vaccines and autism](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/361/8212)

> This question has been disputed so many times...
>   With overwhelming amounts of evidence and research, michaelpri's answer leaves no question open whether vaccines can cause autism or not.

Answer (score 1):

### [Answer by Chris about the effects of laughing.](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/12695/8212)

> I personally thought the question was unanswerable. It seemed to difficult to include diabetes at all, and didn't expect anyone would do more than stating that *laughing won't cure diabetes*.
>   Yet Chris  included a stunning amount of references and links to online copies of those references and wrote an extensive answer, which really will make all future questions regarding laughing duplicates, because every aspect has been included in this answer.
>   Furthermore, the answer inspired this Meta Thread!

Answer (score 0):

### [Answer by JasonC on multivitamin diets](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/8926/8212)

> The great part about this answer is that it actually doesn't support either side, but concludes that *there is no objectivity* in the research done so far.
> And then it goes on to prove beyond doubt that no consensus can be reached regarding this matter, because the data collected is insufficient.